# Rails missing partial *.js.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, renderpartial

I'm trying to inform user about errors without reloading the whole page, but I get an error "AnswersController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant"

create.js.erb

```
$('.answer-errors').html("<%= render 'shared/errors', resource: @answer %>");
```

AnswersController#create

```
def create
  @answer = question.answers.build(answer_params)

  if @answer.save
    redirect_to question, notice: t('.success')
  end
end
```

app/views/shared/_errors.html.slim exist.

app/views/answers/_form.html.slim - this is a form for new answer

```
= form_with model: [question, answer], class: 'form-answer hide' do |form|
 = form.label :body
 = form.text_area :body
 = form.submit 'Save'
```

console log. I see here "Processing by AnswersController#create as HTML" but should it be "..as js"?

```
Started POST "/questions/3/answers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-08-23     21:19:08 +0300
Processing by AnswersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "answer"=>    {"body"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "question_id"=>"3"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Question Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/answers_controller.rb:27:in `question'
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms | Allocations: 4424)

ActionController::UnknownFormat (AnswersController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):
```

Where can be a problem?

Comment: add remote: true in the form

Comment: If you are using `remote: true` (`form_with` defaults to `remote: true`) and its still not working then you have issues with Rails UJS. Check your browser console for errors and ensure that its in your packs or the asset pipeline. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#remote-elements

Comment: @DyaniyalWilson I edited my answer to make it clear that I am using from_with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @max for link to guide.

```
form_with model: [question, answer], class: 'form-answer hide', local: false do..
```

This work fine, but I still don't get why remote: true not the same as local: false. That's counterintuitively to me and any hints will be pleasant

Comment: Because a request from the form is a HTML request, which will reload the page. By setting `remote: true` you are doing a JS call, which does not reload the page.

Comment: @TTD but with remote: true it doesn't work. And the request is sent as HTML you can see the output of console. Only local: false changed that. With remote: true I get:
= form_with model: [question, answer], class: 'form-answer-new hide', remote: true do |form| -  Leads to: Processing by AnswersController#create as HTML and error: ActionController::UnknownFormat (AnswersController#create is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
request.variant: []):

Comment: ..and here already have been flag data-remote="true": <form class="form-answer-edit" action="/answers/79" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true"..